# python flask - serve file on different url

Tags: python, http, flask, werkzeug

I've build an rest server in flask with CRUD for `Order` objects.

So there's an endpoint for `POST /order` to create the `Order` and the user can then upload an attachment on `POST /order/{order_id}/attachment`

I also want to serve the attachment, to be downloadable on the same url.
So that `GET /order/{order_id}/attachment` downloads the attachment file.

But when I return the [werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage), with the `filename` attribute set, the browser gives me an file to save with name: `attachment`

Is there a way to send the file with flask, with the correct filename on an different url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send_from_directory` method might come in handy to serve the file(s).
Example (a bit pseudo-coded):

```
@app.route('/order/{order_id}/attachment')
def download_file(order_id):
    order = get_order_from_db(order_id)

    filename = order.attachment

    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

More on `send_from_directory`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: I know, but the route must end with filename `'/uploads/<path:filename>'`.

Comment: Edited it a bit. Does it look better?

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Also `send_file` works, you can add just an fp to it. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file